# Which version of William Blake's "Jerusalem" did John Reith recite to celebrate the end of the General Strike?

Tags: poetry, william-blake

In his 1PM radio broadcast on 12 May 1926, John Reith, managing director of the BBC, [recited William Blake's "And did those feet in ancient time"](https://www.spectator.co.uk/article/nick-robinson-s-battle-for-the-airwaves) (also known as "Jerusalem") `[1]` to celebrate the end of the General Strike which had lasted for nine days and which the BBC had opposed throughout.

Which version did he use - the one with Blake's original words "these dark Satanic mills", or the one with the altered words "those dark Satanic mills"?

(This information is not included in the [summary of that broadcast](https://wdc.contentdm.oclc.org/digital/collection/strike/id/349/rec/339) which is available in Warwick University's collection.)

(See [another question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/when-and-how-was-the-phrase-these-dark-satanic-mills-in-blakes-jerusalem-fi) which asks about the first usage of the altered words.)

`[1]` ["And did those feet in ancient time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_did_those_feet_in_ancient_time) should not be confused with the much longer poem [Jerusalem The Emanation of the Giant Albion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem_The_Emanation_of_the_Giant_Albion).